# foreach use in netlogo can't not work, it just expected command

Tags: foreach, netlogo

I just try to use foreach in netlogo.
There is 5 station, I want to use the list and create link with each origin station and destination station.

There is my code. I check and always got **"Expected Command."**

```
to link_list
  let origin_list [1 3]
  let destination_list [2 5]
  foreach origin_list destination_list [
    ask stations [ 
      if id = ?1 [
        create-links-with stations with [id = ?2]]]]
end
```

Can any kind expert help me. PLZ

Answer (score 1):

To use `foreach` over two lists simultaneously, the entire call must be enclosed in parens:

```
`(foreach list1 list2 [ ... ])`
```

This is true of any NetLogo primitive that accepts a variable number of arguments. There is always a default number of arguments that works without parens; any other number requires parens.